# Keeping count of values available from among multiple sets

Tags: python, set, combinations, counter

I have the following situation:

I am generating n combinations of size 3 from, made from n values.  Each kth combination [0...n] is pulled from a pool of values, located in the kth index of a list of n sets.  Each value can appear 3 times.  So if I have 10 values, then I have a list of size 10.  Each index holds a set of values 0-10.

So, it seems to me that a good way to do this is to have something keeping count of all the available values from among all the sets.  So, if a value is rare(lets say there is only 1 left), if I had a structure where I could look up the rarest value, and have the structure tell me which index it was located in, then it would make generating the possible combinations much easier.

How could I do this?  What about one structure to keep count of elements, and a dictionary to keep track of list indices that contain the value?

edit:  I guess I should put in that a specific problem I am looking to solve here, is how to update the set for every index of the list (or whatever other structures i end up using), so that when I use a value 3 times, it is made unavailable for every other combination.

Thank you.

**Another edit**

It seems that this may be a little too abstract to be asking for solutions when it's hard to understand what I am even asking for.  I will come back with some code soon, please check back in 1.5-2 hours if you are interested.

Comment: Could you add some code for clarity? I think I follow what you're trying to do, but I'm not picturing what you're starting with very well.

Comment: In the words of Guido, "Code speaks."

Comment: I am just getting started with this part of my program.  When I have some code (in the next couple hours for sure), I will post some.

Answer (score 1):

> how to update the set for every index of the list (or whatever other structures i end up using), so that when I use a value 3 times, it is made unavailable for every other combination.

I assume you want to sample the values truly randomly, right? What if you put 3 of each value into a list, shuffle it with `random.shuffle`, and then just keep popping values from the end of the list when you're building your combination? If I'm understanding your problem right, here's example code:

```
from random import shuffle
valid_values = [i for i in range(10)] # the valid values are 0 through 9 in my example, update accordingly for yours
vals = 3*valid_values # I have 3 of each valid value
shuffle(vals) # randomly shuffle them
while len(vals) != 0:
    combination = (vals.pop(), vals.pop(), vals.pop()) # combinations are 3 values?
    print(combination)
```

EDIT: Updated code based on the added information that you have sets of values (but this still assumes you can use more than one value from a given set):

```
from random import shuffle
my_sets_of_vals = [......] # list of sets
valid_values = list()
for i in range(my_sets_of_vals):
    for val in my_sets_of_vals[i]:
        valid_values.append((i,val)) # this can probably be done in list comprehension but I forgot the syntax
vals = 3*valid_values # I have 3 of each valid value
shuffle(vals) # randomly shuffle them
while len(vals) != 0:
    combination = (vals.pop()[1], vals.pop()[1], vals.pop()[1]) # combinations are 3 values?
    print(combination)
```

Comment: Nice, this is the solution I was imagining also.

Comment: Not random, because each combination is made from a specific set of values.  Set 0  (my very first combination), might have (1,5,9,14,11,28).  And set n (my last combination), might have (0,1,11,16,3) - for example.

Comment: @TravisBlack I guess we don't really understand your problem, then.  Can you at least provide some pseudocode?

Comment: Still, you can trivially modify my code to apply to yours. All you would do is modify how `valid_values` is created. For example, instead of it just being integers, it could be `(set_number,value)` tuples, and when you pop off values, you would use `vals.pop()[1]` instead of `vals.pop()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edit you could make an object for each value. It could hold the number of times you have used the element and the element itself. When you find you have used an element three times, remove it from the list